# Setting Traefik to intercept traffic between Docker containers

Tags: docker, docker-compose, traefik

I have Traefik container (traefik v. 2.8) running as reverse proxy for local development.
I also use docker-compose.yml file to define my services.

Also, I have exposed the services present in `docker-compose.yml` via `host.docker.internal` by setting these lines in my `/etc/hosts` file:

```
127.0.0.1       host.docker.internal
localhost       host.docker.internal
```

My setup is as such:

- host.docker.internal:8443 used for service_a
- host.docker.internal:8453 used for service_b

I have setup Traefik route from a.localhost that goes to host.docker.internal:8443.
I can access `a.localhost` from the host outside the containers just fine, and Traefik does really route the traffic to `host.docker.internal:8443` as I want.

Problem is that I have a reason to have service B (host.docker.internal:8453) call service A via the `a.localhost` hostname.
This does not work, as in service B, I get unknown host when trying to access `a.localhost`

Here is extract from my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  reverse_proxy:
  image: traefik:v2.8
    # Enables the web UI and tells Traefik to listen to docker
    command: --api.insecure=true --providers.docker
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
      # The Web UI (enabled by --api.insecure=true)
      - "9000:8080"
    volumes:
      # So that Traefik can listen to the Docker events
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - ./dev-traefik/traefik.yml:/etc/traefik/traefik.yml
      - ./dev-traefik:/configurations
  
  service_a:
    ports:
      - "8443:8443"

  service_b:
    ports:
      - "8453:8453"
```

Also I'm using a yml-based configuration for Traefik, present in `dynamic-config.yml`:

```
http:
  routers:
    service-a-router:
      service: service-a
      rule: "Host(`a.localhost`)"
      tls: "true" # using tls
  services:
    service-a:
      loadBalancer:
        servers:
          - url: "https://host.docker.internal:8443" # service A

tls:
  certificates:
    - certFile: "/etc/https/tls.crt"
      keyFile: "/etc/https/tls.key"
  stores:
    default:
      defaultCertificate:
        certFile: "/etc/https/tls.crt"
        keyFile: "/etc/https/tls.key"
```

It seems like Traefik is able to listen to requests made from host network, as accessing `https://a.localhost` from browser outside the container network works just fine.
On the other hand, requests made by service_a container don't seem to be caught by Traefik.

What I have also tried is to add `a.localhost` to `/etc/hosts` in the host machine running the containers like this:

```
127.0.0.1   a.localhost
localhost   a.localhost
```

And then using `curl` inside service B container to access service A.

This resulted in getting `connection refused` as opposed to `Could not resolve host: a.localhost`. This leads me to suggest that `traefik` couldn't intercept traffic from service b container

What am I doing wrong?
Is there a way to make such setup work? I do have a legit reason for it, which relates to having as close setup as possible in local development as on other environments which are deployed to cloud.

Comment: Hi Laurenzo, are you sure that your Traefik container is resolving `host.docker.internal` as 127.0.0.1? I think that is not, and what is happening when you add a.localhost in your host file is that service_b is trying to connect to the 127.0.0.1 and is not working. could you try to point a.localhost to your host network address (e.g 192.168.x.x) and confirm what is your traefik container is resolving when try to access to host.docker.internal?

Comment: Hi @mauricubo and thanks for the comment!
I verified that the traefik container does NOT resolve `host.docker.internal` as `127.0.0.1` but as `192.168.65.2` which, according to docker documentation (https://docs.docker.com/desktop/networking/#i-want-to-connect-from-a-container-to-a-service-on-the-host) , "... resolves to the internal IP address used by the host".

I don't follow - why would I need to have traefik container resolve `host.docker.internal` as `127.0.0.1`?

Comment: Hi Laurenzo, I was trying to understand why did you do that, because you said literally that you point `host.docker.internal` on your host machine. But ok, the point is, you can access from service_b to the service_a using the http://service_a:8443 directly. But now, if you want to access using the traefik service you should point the a.localhost to the host IP address (something like 192.168.65.2 a.localhost) not to the 127.0.0.1 because when the service_b try to resolve that server name is looking at your host file and try to access to the 127.0.0.1. Let me know if it is helps

Comment: @mauricubo sorry if the explanation wasn't so clear.
The solution you propose would work otherwise, but what about port mismatch - Traefik should be able to direct traffic from https://a.localhost (on port 443 in host machine) -> host.docker.internal:8443

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to have Traefik intercept container -> container traffic the way I originally specified I'd want, but was able to actually nevertheless get similar setup working.

Here's the scenario:

I have two services that are accessed via HTTP & TLS:

- service_a
- service_b

I want to be able to use `host.docker.internal` special DNS name to my advantage and actually have Traefik to proxy traffic from `https://host.docker.internal/service_a` to `service_a` port 8443 both outside Docker container network (from the host machine running Docker) AND from `service_b` via the fact that both the host machine running Docker can access `host.docker.internal` and also hosts inside the Docker network.
Using this fact to my advantage, I just defined a path for `service_a` as such in Traefik's YML configuration file:

```
http:
  routers:
    service-a-router:
      service: service-a
      rule: "Host(`host.docker.internal`) && PathPrefix(`/service_a`)"
      tls: "true" # using tls
  services:
    service-a:
      loadBalancer:
        servers:
          - url: "https://host.docker.internal:8443" # service A

tls:
  certificates:
    - certFile: "/etc/https/tls.crt"
      keyFile: "/etc/https/tls.key"
  stores:
    default:
      defaultCertificate:
        certFile: "/etc/https/tls.crt"
        keyFile: "/etc/https/tls.key"
```

And `docker-compose.yml` was made to look like this:

```
version: '3'
services:
  reverse_proxy:
  image: traefik:v2.8
    # Enables the web UI and tells Traefik to listen to docker
    command: --api.insecure=true --providers.docker
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
      # The Web UI (enabled by --api.insecure=true)
      - "9000:8080"
    volumes:
      # So that Traefik can listen to the Docker events
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - ./dev-traefik/traefik.yml:/etc/traefik/traefik.yml
      - ./dev-traefik:/configurations
  
  service_a:
    ports:
      - "8443:8443"

  service_b:
    ports:
      - "8453:8453"
```

Now as I use `host.docker.internal` in `Host` rule in my Traefik YML config, Traefik is in fact able to intercept both traffic from the Docker host machine and from the Docker container `service_b`.

`service_b` just need to configure URL of `https://host.docker.internal/service_a` to access `service_a` through Traefik.